# IErrorInfo in c#

Tags: c#, error-handling

There is a C++ COM. And it sometimes throws an exeption on `SomeMethod()`. C++ Com supports `ISupportErrorInfo` and fills `IErrorInfo`. How can I get the `IErrorInfo.Description` in c#?

This code catches the error but there is no cpp message in it.

```
try
{
    COM.SomeMethod()
} 
catch (COMException exn) 
{
    string ACppErrorMessage = exn.message; 
    outputError(ACppErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: can you cast it? something like `(COM as ISupportErrorInfo).Description`

Comment: don't swallow the impotent stuff from your exception do always use `exn.toString()`

Comment: CLOSED. it was problem on c++ side with ISupportErrorInfo.

Comment: @DimDim cool, might be best explaining exactly what the issue was as it might help others in the future.

Comment: @James, Not all Com objects in cpp implemented it, it was only in root one, not in others. quite silly )

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awy7adbx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the `Description` field of `IErrorInfo` maps to `Message` of the exception object *if* `HRESULT` contains that information, otherwise it just populates with the defaults.

If `Message` is empty then I can only assume no information is being returned from the `HRESULT`.

Comment: Message contains a string like: Error. (Exeption HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

Comment: What does `SomeMethod` do?

Comment: Returns an interface. do some math operations (parsing formulas and so).